# url rewrite `/abc/products-` to `/def/products-`

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have many url links in `/abc/` sub-directory, like

```
http://www.domain.com/abc/products-12345
http://www.domain.com/abc/products-23456
http://www.domain.com/abc/products-34567
http://www.domain.com/abc/new-items
```

Now I want to `url rewrite` `/abc/products-`  to `/def/products-`

```
http://www.domain.com/def/products-12345
http://www.domain.com/def/products-23456
http://www.domain.com/def/products-34567
http://www.domain.com/abc/new-items
```

My code in `.htaccess`, but nothing changed. How to rewrite in this case? Thanks.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^abc/products-(.*)$ /def/products-$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can test on [this simulator](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/) the rules should work.

The most probable problem you are facing should be:

- The global configuration does not allow for .htaccess overwrite
- .htaccess is not readable for apache user
- You have no mod_rewrite active on this apache server, thus no trigger to `<IfModule>` directive.

Best troubleshooting option would be trying a redirection of all page to a static page. If this does not work, look for a configuration problem.

Comment: ,I am sure mod_rewrite is allowed, I could do other url rewrite like `RewriteRule ^feed/rss.xml$ rss/rss.php [L]`, but `RewriteRule ^abc/products-(.*)$ /def/products-$1 [L,R=301]` not work in this case. do u have any working code? I am now testing in `http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/`, still not find a solution.

Comment: Did you also tried removing the `RewriteBase` directive? Unless you have an alias, it seems useless to me. But this may change nothing more. Furthermore, is your `.htaccess` located in the site root directory, or within the `abc/` directory?

Comment: thanks, remove `RewriteBase`, works.